# Error al ingresar codigo html5 a la base de datos con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Trabajo en un proyecto `php` en el que el usuario puede crear articulos web en el que al guardar los cambios, se ejecuta un ajax que envia un `formData` al servidor, donde se procesa para que se guarden en la base de datos.

Hasta el momento todo funcionaba de maravilla. Pero ahora que migre de servidor, mi proyecto me empezo a lanzar un error, el cual es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(SINTAXIS DEL ERROR)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
<title> 403 Forbidden
</title></head>
<body style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;">
<div style="height:auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align: center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;">
        <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">403</h1>
<h2 style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Forbidden
</h2>
<p>Access to this resource on the server is denied!</p>
```

Muchos diran que revise el .htaccess, o ver que las carpetas y los archivos tengan los permisos correspondientes...  la verdad es que ya lo hice, y ese no es el problema.

He rebuscado cual es el problema y encontre que el error se encuentra en el momento de ejecutar el sql que guarda los cambios del articulo.

les muestro:

```
$sql = "UPDATE resumenEjecutivo SET
                    temaResumen='".$this->temaResumen."',
                    PDC='".$this->PDC."',
                    ACD='".$this->ACD."',
                    borrador='".$this->getBorrador()."',
                    fechaModificacion=NOW()
                    WHERE
                    idResumenEjecutivo=".$this->idResumenEjecutivo;

            $res = $this->bd->query($sql);
```

Hasta este punto esta consulta y la forma de ejecutarlo, esta bien, porque si envie cambios con valores vacios, ejecuta perfectamente el update.

El problema que logro ver es que, ya que el html que se crea al crear el articulo, lleva comillas:

```
<p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: arial; color: black;">Prueba de envio</p>
```

Justo las comillas se encuentran en el atributo style, por lo que deduzco que, el problema es que no puedo meter eso dentro de una variable ya que lleva comillas dobles, y no importa si uso comillas simples o dobles a la hora de meterlo en una variable (`$sql="";` o `$sql='';`) siempre tendre problemas con sql o con php ya que se concatena en una de las dos.

Es como si hiciera esto:

```
$sql = "UPDATE resumenEjecutivo SET
                    temaResumen='<p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: arial; color: black;">Tema</p>',
                    PDC='<p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: arial; color: black;">propuesta</p>',
                    ACD='<p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: arial; color: black;">Acuerdo</p>',
                    borrador='1',
                    fechaModificacion=NOW()
                    WHERE
                    idResumenEjecutivo=970";

            $res = $this->bd->query($sql);
```

Como notan si ejecuto esa consulta con php, tendria un problema ya que la comilla doble estaria concatenando mi cadena de texto, lo que desconfigura totalmente mi consulta, mostrandome el error que aparece. Por ello es que al ejecutarse, el servidor detecta como si el archivo fuera malicioso o algo asi.

¿Hay alguna funcion de php o en javascript o algo que me permita que las comillas dobles de las etiquetas html pasen desapercibidas en la cadena, y se ejecute bien la consulta?, ¿O pueden ayudarme a encontrar alguna solución para este problema?

Comment: Aunque quizá sea una pésima idea guardar este tipo de contenido en la BD, prueba a escapar las comillas dobles en el contenido, para ello debes anteponer ``\`` a cada comilla.

Comment: ¿Porque seria una pésima idea?, Aunque si pense en esa solución, pero ¿como se las puedo poner si el html se genera automaticamente mientras el usuario digita el articulo?

Comment: Pues debes ponerlo en el código que recibe los artículos y genera el contenido. Y puede que sea una pésima idea porque podría haber otras formas.